# last summer or the last summer?

Tags: grammar

I've read `Essential Grammar in Use` Raymond Murphy's book. some page of the book was told me:

> Do not use "the" with:
>
> television
>
> breakfast/lunch/dinner
>
> next/last + week/month/year/summer/Monday/etc.

e.g.

> Did you have a holiday last summer?

My question is can i speak:

> Did you have a holiday in the last summer?

Is it really that i can not use `a` or `the` with all of them above?

for example:

> a television, the television, the last month, ...

I'm a little bit confusing. Is that rule depend on its context or it is always true?

Note that this question might be duplicated but i expect the answer that emphasise on the additional explanation according to the context above that i referred from the book to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

"Did you have a holiday last summer?" asks did you have a holiday in the previous summer. "Did you have a holiday in the last summer?" asks did you have a holiday in the last summer (implying that there will be no more summers)